# Field separator in AWK

Tags: shell-script

I have a txt file in which i have records like

```
cat,bdb awq,sdcsidsjo hhhd 
xs,dun,hat ase, xsdfc
xd,yu,nor acc,cuiov dfvgf
```

I want the output only this below words (second column after space).

```
awq
ase
acc
```

I tried the commands like
`awk '{print $2}'`, `awk 'BEGIN {print $2} { FS="," }'`, `awk '{print $2 FS=","}'`, `awk 'BEGIN{ORS=",";} {print $2}'`
but nothing worked, can any one know how to get it.

I have edited the question in my first column i have comma,s in it, if i use awk 'BEGIN { FS="," } {print $2}'

I am getting the result as
bdb
dun 
yu

but i want the result like to be shown as
awq
ase
acc

Can any one know how to get the result.

Answer (score 2):

(Updated for updated question)

It looks like you want to extract the first word after a space, up until the next comma.

```
$ awk -F ' ' '{ split($2,a,","); print a[1] }' <file
awq
ase
acc
```

This treats the data as space-delimited, then takes the second space-delimited field and splits it explicitly on commas, and prints the first resulting string from that result.

Alternatively, with `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/^[^ ]* //; s/,.*$//' <file
awq
ase
acc
```

This uses two substitutions to first remove the bit up to the first space, and then the bit from the comma.  The remaining string is printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Command: for i in `echo "cbdb awq,sdcsidsjo hhhd xsdunh ase, xsdfc xdyun acc,cuiov dfvgf" | awk -F "," '{print $1,$2,$3}'`;   do echo $i | awk '/^a/{print $0}'; done|tr "\n" " "
```

input

```
cbdb awq,sdcsidsjo hhhd xsdunh ase, xsdfc xdyun acc,cuiov dfvgf
```

output

command

```
for i in `echo "cbdb awq,sdcsidsjo hhhd xsdunh ase, xsdfc xdyun acc,cuiov dfvgf" | awk -F "," '{print $1,$2,$3}'`;   do echo $i | awk '/^a/{print $0}'; done|tr "\n" " "
```

output

```
awq ase acc
```